# How to add a drop shadow for SplitView.Pane

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dropshadow, windows-community-toolkit

How to add a drop shadow for `SplitView.Pane`?

I tried `DropShadowPanel` from the UWP Community Toolkit UI Controls and wrote something like this:

```
<SplitView DisplayMode="Overlay" PanePlacement="Right" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <controls:DropShadowPanel>
            <Frame Name="DetailsFrame" />
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>
     </SplitView.Pane>
 </SplitView>
```

However, the shadow appears inside the pane, while I want it to be outside `SplitView.Pane`, wrapping it.
How can I implement that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The DropShadowPanel Control allows the creation of a drop shadow effect for any Xaml FrameworkElement in the markup. You can control the following property of the drop shadow effect : Offset, Color, Opactity and Blur Radius.

I did not find that you have set property of the `DropShadowPanel` . If all the property of the `DropShadowPanel` are default value, the `DropShadowPanel` will have no effect as except. You could create `DropShadowPanel` by the following code. And this is official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DropShadowPanel) you could refer to.

```
 <SplitView.Pane>
     <control:DropShadowPanel  BlurRadius="5" ShadowOpacity="0.5" Color="Black" OffsetX="10" OffsetY="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center">
         <TextBlock Text="Pane"
        FontSize="24"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
     </control:DropShadowPanel>
 </SplitView.Pane>
```