# How to create a DropShadow for a SplitView.Pane like in Edge

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, dropshadow, windows-community-toolkit

I am currently trying to create a SplitView.Pane that looks kinda like the edge browser history/favourites pane. Therefore, I need a shadow at the (left) border of my SplitView.Pane.

To create the shadow, I use the DropShadowPanel from the UWP Toolkit. The idea is something like this (doesn't work, of course):

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel>
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <!--Content-->
    </SplitView.Pane>
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

The shadow should be outside the panel. How do I get this done?

This is how the shadow should look like:

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2mHr.png)

EDIT: The DropShadow should be OUTSIDE the pane. The duplicate-post's answer creates a shadow inside the pane. Unless i miss something there.

Comment: Looks like already asked question or duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395093/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-for-splitview-pane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a drop shadow for SplitView.Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395093/how-to-add-a-drop-shadow-for-splitview-pane)

Comment: You're missing out the question the person asked, I'll quote: _However, the shadow appears inside the pane, while I want it to be outside SplitView.Pane, wrapping it. How can I implement that? Thanks!_

Comment: Yea, I read that. Yet the answer does not solve my issue since it creates a shadow inside the pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't simply apply a shadow to the `Pane`'s direct child as it will appear being cut off. You can of course try overriding the `SplitView`'s *style* and applying the shadow directly onto the `Pane` element, but you will soon find out that the `PaneRoot` has its own *Clipping* logic defined in XAML, so if you were not careful, you could potentially break its underlying UI logic.

Here's a simple solution that works without modifying the style. The idea is to apply the shadow on an inner element where there's enough space between this element and the `Pane`'s root element for the shadow to spread out.

Assume the `PanePlacement` is set to `Right`, then your root element, a `Border`(i.e. `RootBorder`), should have a *left* padding(i.e. `12,0,0,0`) that matches the `BlurRadius`(i.e. `12`) of the `DropShadowPanel`.

Also, the `PaneBackground` needs to be *transparent* otherwise it will cover up the shadow. Instead, the background color should then be applied to a container element(i.e. `PaneContentGrid`) that's inside the root element.

Please see the code below for a simple example -

**XAML**

```
<SplitView PanePlacement="Right" PaneBackground="Transparent">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Border x:Name="RootBorder" Padding="12,0,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="12"
                                          Color="Black"
                                          Opacity="0.3"
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Rectangle Fill="White" />
                </controls:DropShadowPanel>

                <!-- SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush is the default PaneBackground brush, feel free to change it to whatever you like! -->
                <Grid x:Name="PaneContentGrid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">
                    <!-- place your Panel content here. -->
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That does the trick. Many thanks for your detailed solution.